# how to resize image size(quality) with codeigniter image_lib

Tags: php, codeigniter, image-processing, gd

we are creating an application which allows image upload, now we want to reduce the image size to reduce the page load time, now this is the code i'm using, it doesn't work, image size remains 100% it doesn't reduce, please help maybe i'm missing something or i'm doing something wrong

```
if(!empty($_FILES['image_field']['name']))
{
    $config['upload_path'] = 'image_folder';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|png';
    $config['max_size'] = '262144';
    $config['file_name'] = 'my_image_name';
    $this->load->library('upload',$config);
    if(!$this->upload->do_upload('image_field'))
    {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('error','<div class="alert alert-warning">Something went wrong...try again...</div>');
        redirect('Controller/function_name');
    }
    else
    {
        $type = array('image/png'=>'png','image/jpg'=>'jpg','image/jpeg'=>'jpg');
        $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
        $config['source_image'] = base_url().'image_folder'.$config['file_name'].'.'.$type[$_FILES['image_field']['type']];
        $config['quality'] = '50%';
        $this->load->library('image_lib', $config);
        $this->image_lib->resize();
        // save to database    
    }
}
```

i'm using codeigniter 3.0

Comment: you may take alook [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39416169/2368696) or directly [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14072710/2368696)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48568927/image-compress-in-codeigniter3

Answer (score 3):

You should use without `%` as integer like that:

```
$config['quality'] = 50;
```

Comment: I don't see 'quality' listed as an option in the `File Uploading Class` docs at http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html ... ... but I see from your example that it is an option in the `Image Manipulation Class` at http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/image_lib.html

Comment: @dsdsdsdsd yes, `quality` option in `image_lib` class.

Answer (score 1):

```
 $config['image_library']    = 'gd2';
 $config['quality']      = 60;
```

works great adjust the quality and check the image file size it save. will be different.

Answer (score 0):

I also had to set my `image_library` parameter to "gd" before the quality change started working. I wonder why it didn't work with "gd2"

```
$config['image_library']    = 'gd';
$config['quality']      = 40;
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this would **not work** for me using the **GD or GD2 library**.
In order for the "**quality**" to be affected - I needed to use the "**ImageMagick**" Library.

As stated in the documentation - if you use either the "**ImageMagick**" or the "**NetPBM**" library - "**you must supply the path**": https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/image_lib.html

On my GoDaddy server the path was "**/usr/bin**"

```
    $config['source_image'] = $source_image;
    $config['library_path'] = '/usr/bin';
    $config['image_library'] = 'ImageMagick';
    $config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
    $config['quality'] = "20%"; // Maintained the aspect ratio and dimensions but reduced the file size by about 60%

    $this->image_lib->initialize($config);
    if(!$this->image_lib->resize()){
                    echo "QUCKVIEW Re-sizing - ";
                    echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();
                    echo "Image Resize for Grooming Quickview Failed! Contact System Administrator.";
                    die();
                }
```