# Image compress in Codeigniter3

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a piece of code where I compress images via Codeigniter gd2 library. However, it turns this photo

[image]

into this one

[image]

because I set width and height in my code. However, when I remove these 2 lines, `$config['quality']` property does not work. How can I solve this problem and save the actual size of the image compressing it?

Here is my code:

```
 $image_datar = $this->upload->data();  
 $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';  
 $config['source_image'] = './assets/img/single_courses/'.$image_datar["file_name"];  
 $config['maintain_ratio'] = false;
 $config['quality'] = '60%';
 $config['width'] = '750';
 $config['height'] = '500';
 $config['new_image'] = './assets/img/single_courses/'.$image_datar["file_name"];  
 $this->load->library('image_lib', $config);  
 $this->image_lib->resize();
 $post_image = $image_datar["file_name"];
```

Comment: Hmmm So exactly what do you mean by `compressed`

Comment: @RiggsFolly make 2MB image file a 500KB image file

Comment: are the original images you want to resize always the same size?

Comment: @Vickel I want them to be the same size but lower quality

Comment: ok, then you need to get the source image size, I suppose you find that in $image_datar. Try to print_r($image_datar); Then you set config height and width dynamically.If not use php function getimagesize(), see here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php

Comment: @Vickel I rarely use `image_lib` because its ambiguity (I like verot class upload better), but won't the width and height not change if you just leave those out and just affect the quality? if not - that's some crappy functionality.

Comment: here is what you can set: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/image_lib.html#preferences. It doesn't look like you need to set height and width. Did you compare the size of source and new image? because even with a quality of 30% you might not see too much of a difference, just a different file-size...

Comment: @Vickel turns out it is not so simple, CI has a line that basically just copies the file if the width/height aren't different and completely subverts any image "resizing" and thus quality changes. I personally really really hate CI's image library.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit confusing what you are trying to accomplish even after reading the comments, and your code as it specifies the width. **If you want it to be 750x500 by have the same ratio (so things don't look "compressed")** than you should have `$config['maintain_ratio'] = true;` which generates:

[image]

If you just want to reduce the quality of the image so that the **file size is smaller yet keep the same dimensions** of the original image than one would think you can comment out the width and height of the config. However, in my testing that yielded the *exact* same file size as the original image, even when changing the quality down to 10%. Weird, bug? I confirmed this with `filesize()` and in my os!

Turns out not a bug, but a coded feature:

```
// If the target width/height match the source, AND if the new file name is not equal to the old file name
// we'll simply make a copy of the original with the new name... assuming dynamic rendering is off.
if ($this->dynamic_output === FALSE && $this->orig_width === $this->width && $this->orig_height === $this->height)
{
    if ($this->source_image !== $this->new_image && @copy($this->full_src_path, $this->full_dst_path))
    {
        chmod($this->full_dst_path, $this->file_permissions);
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

I've tried to figure out a way to get around this but that would require overwriting and messing with the libraries functionality. For now, and if your ok with your image being 1px less in width and height than the original, you can do something like:

```
$source = $this->frontend_image_upload_path . 'org/upload_original.jpg';
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($source);
$config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
$config['source_image'] = $source;
//$config['maintain_ratio'] = true;
$config['quality'] = '20%';
$config['width'] = $width - 1;
$config['height'] = $height - 1;
$config['new_image'] = $this->frontend_image_upload_path . 'org/new_image.jpg';
$this->load->library('image_lib', $config);
if (!$this->image_lib->resize()) {
    echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();
}
```

Comment: I did not get 1 thing. The first code, what does it mean? Should I include this code in my controller? or it is just example?

Comment: The first code is if you actually want to change the dimensions to 700 by whatever as you specified in your original code. The second code and is if you don't, and just want to reduce the file size as you said in comments.