# How to resize multiple image files on upload?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have the following php code for uploading:

```
$data = array();
$filesCount = count($_FILES['img']['name']);
for($i = 0; $i < $filesCount; $i++)
{
    $_FILES['userFile']['name'] = $_FILES['img']['name'][$i];
    $_FILES['userFile']['type'] = $_FILES['img']['type'][$i];
    $_FILES['userFile']['tmp_name'] = $_FILES['img']['tmp_name'][$i];
    $_FILES['userFile']['error'] = $_FILES['img']['error'][$i];
    $_FILES['userFile']['size'] = $_FILES['img']['size'][$i];


    $id = $this->session->userdata('ses_id');
    $tabel = $this->session->userdata('ses_tabel');
    if (!file_exists('uploads/'.$tabel.'/kategori'))
    {
        mkdir('uploads/'.$tabel.'/kategori', 0777, true);
    }else{  
        $uploadPath = 'uploads/'.$tabel.'/kategori';
        $newname = $idkategori.'_'.$nama;
        $config['upload_path'] = $uploadPath;
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|png|jpeg';
        $config['file_name'] = $newname;

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        $this->upload->initialize($config);
        if($this->upload->do_upload('userFile')){
            $fileData = $this->upload->data();
            $cfg['image_library'] = 'gd2';
            $cfg['quality'] = '50%';
            $this->load->library('image_lib');
            $this->image_lib->initialize($cfg);
            $this->image_lib->resize();
            $uploadData[$i]['nama'] = $this->input->post('nama_kategori');
            $uploadData[$i]['file_name'] = $fileData['file_name'];
            $uploadData[$i]['created'] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
            $uploadData[$i]['modified'] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
            $uploadData[$i]['id_resto'] = $id;
            $uploadData[$i]['id_kategori'] = $idkategori;
        }
    }
}
```

My file gets uploaded but is not resized, I want to resize image so that when I request it on an Android device, the image file is not too big.
If possible please help me resize width and height too.

sorry for bad english,
thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the path of the newly uploaded image for the image lib config.

Read more [here](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/image_lib.html#processing-an-image).

```
    $this->upload->initialize($config, true);  // important 2nd param
    if ($this->upload->do_upload('userFile')) {
        $fileData = $this->upload->data();
        $cfg['source_image'] = $fileData['full_path'];
        list($width, $height) = getimagesize($fileData['full_path']);
        $cfg['width'] = $width - 1;
        $cfg['height'] = $height - 1;
        $cfg['image_library'] = 'gd2';
        $cfg['quality'] = '50%';
        $this->load->library('image_lib');
        $this->image_lib->initialize($cfg);
        if (!$this->image_lib->resize()) {
            log_message('error', 'resize failed: ' . $this->image_lib->display_errors());
        }
        $this->image_lib->clear();
        $uploadData[$i]['nama'] = $this->input->post('nama_kategori');
        $uploadData[$i]['file_name'] = $fileData['file_name'];
        $uploadData[$i]['created'] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        $uploadData[$i]['modified'] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        $uploadData[$i]['id_resto'] = $id;
        $uploadData[$i]['id_kategori'] = $idkategori;
    }
```

**UPDATE:**

*If you only want to change quality:*

So I forgot I already answered this type of question before. If you dig into the image library code you will notice that the quality variable is only used when something actually needs to be resized! CI checks to see if the image size matches the designated output size and if it is a match or if the image width and height aren't specified in the config it just moves on... Thus the quality will never be affected. To *hack* around this you can get the width and height and subtract 1px. I wouldn't call it a bug but more of an oversight.

I personally don't like CI's upload or image lib and use https://github.com/verot/class.upload.php (this issue is not a problem there).

Here is the answer where I figured this all out: [Image compress in Codeigniter3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48568927/image-compress-in-codeigniter3)

Comment: thanks for reply your code no error but it does not work, the file size is same when i upload 1mb

Comment: oh wait your sparking my memory now... i answered this question before... as i recall the only way to change the quality is to actually change the size of the image! its a weird thing of the image library. i believe the solution i presented was to knock off one pixel from the width and height.

Answer (score 0):

This function uses PHP's GD library and will resize an image while maintaining the proper aspect ratio of the original image.  You can also crop the image so it will crop and fill the space of desired dimensions.  Just play around with some of the settings.

```
function scaleMyImage($filePath, $newPath, $newSize, $crop = NULL){

  $img = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($filePath));

  $dst_x = 0;
  $dst_y = 0;

  $width   = imagesx($img);
  $height  = imagesy($img);

  $newWidth   = $newSize;
  $newHeight  = $newSize;

  $aspectRatio = $width/$height;

  if($width < $height){  //Portrait.

    if($crop){

      $newWidth   = floor($width * ($newSize / $width));
      $newHeight  = floor($height * ($newSize / $width));
      $dst_y = (floor(($newHeight - $newSize)/2)) * -1;

    }else{

      $newWidth = floor($width * ($newSize / $height));
      $newHeight = $newSize;
      $dst_x = floor(($newSize - $newWidth)/2);

      }


  } elseif($width > $height) {  //Landscape


    if($crop){

      $newWidth   = floor($width * ($newSize / $height));
      $newHeight  = floor($height * ($newSize / $height));
      $dst_x = (floor(($newWidth - $newSize)/2)) * -1;


    }else{

      $newWidth = $newSize;
      $newHeight = floor($height * ($newSize / $width));
      $dst_y = floor(($newSize - $newHeight)/2);

      }


    }

  $finalImage = imagecreatetruecolor($newSize, $newSize);
  imagecopyresampled($finalImage, $img, $dst_x, $dst_y, 0, 0, $newWidth, $newHeight, $width, $height);

  //header('Content-Type: image/jpeg'); //<--Comment our if you want to save to file.
  imagejpeg($finalImage, $newPath, 60); //<--3rd param is quality.  60 does good job.  You can play around.

  imagedestroy($img);
  imagedestroy($finalImage);

}

$filePath = 'path/to/image.jpg';
$newPath = NULL; //Set to NULL to output to browser, otherwise provide a  filepath to save.
$newSize = 400; //Pixels
$crop = 1;  //Set to NULL if you don't want to crop.

scaleMyImage($filePath, $newPath, $newSize, $crop);
```

Comment: how exactly does this address OPs concern given the context that he is using CodeIgniters built in image library? this is just a function dump

Comment: @Alex OP did not specifically limit the response to Codeigniter's image library.  He can choose to use it if he wants to. It does what he asked for.

Comment: that's a cop-out in my opinion esp. considering the image library code is right there and just needs to be slightly modified to work. if everyone were to answer off-base the overall quality would go downhill.

Comment: @Alex It's not a cop-out.  If he had asked for a Codeigniter only fix I would not have answered the question at all.  I know nothing about Codeigniter.  I'm glad you were able to offer a better answer.  Seems like the system worked as intended.

Answer (score 0):

Hey brother try this code to resize image

```
 $fileData = $this->upload->data();

                            $configer =  array(
                                         'image_library'   => 'gd2',
                                          'source_image'    =>  $fileData['full_path'],
                                          'maintain_ratio'  =>  TRUE,
                                          'quality' => '40%' );

                                $this->image_lib->clear();
                                $this->image_lib->initialize($configer);
                                $this->image_lib->resize();
```

Comment: thanks for reply, i try your code but that's make it error